# auto_arima parameter question

Tags: arima

I was reading some documentation when I came across this function:

```
model = auto_arima(y,
m=12,
seasonal=True,
stationary=True,
trace=True, error_action=’ignore’, suppress_warnings=True)
model.fit(y)
```

The y is just a numpy array, but waht does the m=12 refer to?

Comment: [The documentation](https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html) states that `m` is the period of seasonal differencing. This fit was probably made to monthly data with yearly seasonality (12 months to a year), or perhaps to data in 2-hour buckets with daily seasonality (12 such buckets to a day).